# IE 7/8 gap between the two elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i found a little problem in IE 7/8 
Example:

```
  problem is probably here 

  #sequence-theme .title {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  left: 65%;
  padding:10px 30px 10px 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom:1%;
  zoom: 1;
  z-index: 50;
  }
```

[image]
[image]

i think something is wrong in css...
Somebody please help me with this ?

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YJ6ZJ/embedded/result/)

**Thanks**

Comment: Try setting `margin: 0` on both elements.

Comment: i just tried...bud still same

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a fixed height and `display:block`.